# Table not reflected while running file.sql using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I wanted to run a `.sql` file populated with queries.

`queries.sql`

```sql
DROP TABLE USERS;

CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    USERID integer not null primary key,
    USERNAME char(8),
    FIRSTNAME varchar(30),
    LASTNAME varchar(30),
    CITY varchar(30),
    STATE char(2),
    EMAIL varchar(100),
    PHONE char(14),
    LIKESPORTS bit not null default 0,
    LIKETHEATRE bit not null default 0,
    LIKECONCERTS bit not null default 0,
    LIKEJAZZ bit not null default 0,
    LIKECLASSICAL bit not null default 0,
    LIKEOPERA bit not null default 0,
    LIKEROCK bit not null default 0,
    LIKEVEGAS bit not null default 0,
    LIKEBROADWAY bit not null default 0,
    LIKEMUSICALS bit not null default 0
);

INSERT INTO USERS (USERID,USERNAME,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,CITY,STATE,EMAIL,PHONE,LIKESPORTS,LIKETHEATRE,LIKECONCERTS,LIKEJAZZ,LIKECLASSICAL,LIKEOPERA,LIKEROCK,LIKEVEGAS,LIKEBROADWAY,LIKEMUSICALS)         VALUES ('1','JSG99FHE','Rafael','Taylor','Kent','WA','Etiam.laoreet.libero@sodalesMaurisblandit.edu','(664) 602-4412','TRUE','TRUE',0,'TRUE','FALSE',0,0,'TRUE','FALSE','TRUE')
INSERT INTO USERS (USERID,USERNAME,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,CITY,STATE,EMAIL,PHONE,LIKESPORTS,LIKETHEATRE,LIKECONCERTS,LIKEJAZZ,LIKECLASSICAL,LIKEOPERA,LIKEROCK,LIKEVEGAS,LIKEBROADWAY,LIKEMUSICALS)         VALUES ('2','PGL08LJI','Vladimir','Humphrey','Murfreesboro','SK','Suspendisse.tristique@nonnisiAenean.edu','(783) 492-1886',0,0,0,'TRUE','TRUE',0,0,'TRUE','FALSE','TRUE')
```

I learnt that by using `sqlcmd` you can run the sql file. The command I ran was

```
sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-MAA8HLG -d TICKET -i D:\BIT2016\queries.sql
```

The above command ran successfully. However, when viewed in SQL Server Management Studio, pinged the table, I got the error saying:

> Invalid object name 'USERS'

Any idea what could be the issue? Even though the queries got executed using command line, why isn't it getting reflected while I am using the table in SQL Server Management Studio.

@Larnu: SELECT [Name] FROM TICKET.sys.tables WHERE [name] = N'USERS'; do you get any results?

[image]

UPDATE:

ITS WORKING. I have to explicitly write 'USE TICKET;' and then ran the query it worked !!!

Comment: @Lamu In the command, i have written  -d Ticket (database)

Comment: L a r n u ... please.

Comment: The image (which I removed) didn't add anything to your question though. It was just an image of a login screen. If you *were* to display an image it *should* be of the object explorer expanded to the tables node for the `TICKET` database. If you use the query `SELECT [Name] FROM TICKET.sys.tables WHERE [name] = N'USERS';` do you get any results?

Comment: Thanks Larnu!! For Use database syntax.